# How do you import a range based off a common cell value/date across 2 entire sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I am looking to import a column/data based off a common date.

Currently using =TODAY()+2 in "Sheet A" to get the date. I have another sheet ("Sheet B"), which has data that is updated every day automatically, with a row of dates.

[Data which is updated daily](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c6VI8.png)

I want my spreadsheet to import the column of data in "Sheet B" based on the date generated by =TODAY()+2 in "Sheet A".

For reference, the date I would want today would be in 'DL7' in "Sheet B". And the cell =TODAY()+2 is in is 'O1' in "Sheet A".

Answer (score 1):

You can use [FILTER()](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093197) to get the data column in "SheetB" based on the date value in "SheetA"

### Sample:

**SheetB:**

[image]

**SheetA:**

[image]

**Formula:**

```
SheetA A1: =today()+2
SheetA B1: =filter(SheetB!A2:AD,SheetB!A2:AD2=A1)
```

### What it does?

- I provided the range of data to be filtered which is `SheetB!A2:AD`
- I want to filter the data based on its date that matched the value in SheetA A1,  Hence the condition would be `SheetB!A2:AD2=A1`

---

### (Update)

If SheetA and SheetB is in a separate Google Sheet. You can use this formula in SheetA B1:

```
=filter(importrange("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1RPQ7WOTOZZSirf60kP6nULhViCdsuGHcOxxxxx/edit","SheetB!A2:AD"),index(importrange("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1RPQ7WOTOZZSirf60kP6nULhViCdsuGHcOxxxxx/edit","SheetB!A2:AD"),1,0)=A1)
```

### What it does?

1. We used [IMPORTRANGE()](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093340) to import our data from another Google Sheet
2. We used [INDEX()](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098242) to get our imported data's row 1 values. Which will be used as a criteria for our [FILTER()](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093197)

### Output:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the reply - is there a way of using this across two google sheets, like import range?

Comment: I see, so that's what you mean by another sheet. I thought it is another tab in the same Google Sheet. Anyways, please see the updated answer as reference on how to apply filter to the imported data.